# Divide two-digit numbers into two separate parts in python

Tags: python

I want to divide a two-digit number into two different parts
For example: 12 to 1 and 2, 87 to 8 and 7
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Your integer number is in 'num' variable
num = str(num)
a, b = num[0], num[1]
```

Comment: Or just `a, b = str(num)`